Python multiprocessing , how to avoid creating a tuple with million objects
New to python multiprocessing.
I have a task that involves hitting a webservice some million times and save response in a file (separate file for each request).
I have got the high-level working code but little confuse on couple of things.

What is the difference between following two syntaxes?
pool = Pool(processes=4) 
pool.starmap(task, listOfInputParametersTuple)

and
with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
     pool.starmap(task, listOfInputParametersTuple)


Is there a way to avoid reading the entire input file before starting the multiprocessing Pool?  Basically, read each line and immediately spawn a pool task.
with open (list_of_ids, 'r') as infile:
    for id in infile:
       listOfInputParametersTuple.append( tuple ((id, queue, requestBodyTemplate))
    pool.starmap(task, listOfInputParametersTuple)


In the task, I use a fairly large requestBodyTemplate and passed id to create a JSON request. This requestBodyTemplate variable is duplicated in each element of the input tuple. Is there a way to pass it to the task function outside of input-tuple.

How do one ensure that all spawned tasks are finished before exiting the main program?

Any pointers on timing out the task if it is taking too long so to release the pool?


Feel free to share any other suggestions you may have.
Objective:

Read a list of 1 million IDs from a file
For each id, craft a JSON.
Request a webservice with above created JSON. (takes few seconds to get response)
Save output of response to a directory.
Save status to a unified "status" file

Task:
def task(i,queue):

    # get the current process
    process = current_process()

    # generate some work
    s = random.randint(1, 10)

    # block to simulate work
    print (f"TASK function : {process} - sleep for {s} sec")
    sleep(s)

    data = f"{process} - sleep {s} sec - {i} - {queue}"

    print (f"TASK function: {data}")

    # put it on the queue
    queue.put(data)

Main method:
def main ():

    set_start_method('spawn')
    pool = Pool(processes=4)

    requestBodyTemplate = getRequestBodyTemplateJSON()

    with open (list_of_ids, 'r') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            listOfInputParametersTuple.append( tuple ((line, queue , requestBodyTemplate))

    # set the fork start method
    # create the manager
    with Manager() as  manager:
        # create the shared queue
        queue = manager.Queue()

        Process(target=listener, args=(queue,)).start()
        print ("back in main after starting listener ")

        # execute the tasks_i in parallel # use starmap to have multiple params 
        pool.starmap(task, listOfInputParametersTuple)
        # pool.starmap(task, zip ( args_i, itertools.repeat(queue)))

        pool.close()
        pool.join()

        # wait for all tasks to get over
        sleep(10)

        print ("\n Sending None message to queue ")
        queue.put(None)


You can do this using imap() instead of starmap(). Both map() and starmap() AFAICT will iterate and chop the iterable before starting any task, so even writing a generator function to supply the items would just read the whole file. This is not explicitly stated in the Python docs, but it is hinted at here:

This method chops the iterable into a number of chunks which it submits to the process pool as separate tasks. The (approximate) size of these chunks can be specified by setting chunksize to a positive integer.
Note that it may cause high memory usage for very long iterables. Consider using imap() or imap_unordered() with explicit chunksize option for better efficiency.

On the other hand, imap() and imap_unordered() get the input parameters lazily, and the iterator they return also allows you to get one element at a time specifying a timeout. You will however have to change the signature of your task() function to take only one argument and unpack the tuple in the function body.
requestBodyTemplate = getRequestBodyTemplateJSON()

def gen_params_from_file(path, queue):
    with open (path, 'r') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            yield (line, queue, requestBodyTemplate)


Then later:
with Manager() as  manager:
    queue = manager.Queue()
    ...

    res = pool.imap(task, gen_params_from_file(list_of_ids, queue))

    while 1:
        try:
            res.next(timeout=10)
        except multiprocessing.context.TimeoutError:
            ... # do something
        except StopIteration:
            # We are done
            break


Note that if the specific order of results is not important (it usually isn't), imap_unordered is the better option (it means you get each result as it finishes, without having faster results delayed by slower tasks that were dispatched first).
